# Primefaces 5.0 Chart Customization-Bar Chart Grid Lines & Labels

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, bar-chart

I need to change colors of the grid lines and axis labels of bar chart. I have changed background color of the **.jqplot-series-canvas** and grid lines just disapeared.

For changing labels of x and y axis' text colors, i have tried to change it with css by using this :

```
.jqplot-yaxis-tick
{
    color:#ffffff !important;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

**.xhtml file**

```
<p:chart type="bar"
  model="#{dashboardController.monthOfYearBarModel}" styleClass="chart"
  style="width:1000px;height:400px; margin: 0 auto;" />
```

**bean .java file**

```
monthOfYearBarModel = new BarChartModel();
monthOfYearBarModel.setSeriesColors("e3e3e3");
feesByMonthsOfCurrentYear = new ChartSeries();
feesByMonthsOfCurrentYear.setLabel("Monthly");
monthOfYearBarModel.setTitle("Monthly");
Axis xFeeOfMonthAxis = monthOfYearBarModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
xFeeOfMonthAxis.setLabel("Months");
Axis yFeeOfMonthAxis = monthOfYearBarModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
yFeeOfMonthAxis.setLabel("Fee");
```

I couldn't find how to change the jqplot-axis-tick's and grid lines' colors.How can i change it?

You can see the chart from http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml